# cannot resolve "{% static 'images/image_name.jpg' %}

Tags: django, pycharm, django-staticfiles

I am new to `django` and cannot seem to load images with `bootstrap`.
I'm getting the error

> cannot resolve "{% static 'images/image_name.jpg'  %}

I understand that it is not finding the path. 
Notice that `index.html` is in `products/templates` and `base.html` is in `templates/` . `index.html` extends `base.html`.

Please tell me where am i setting the `path` wrong?

This is my folder structure

> `folder structure`

```
E:.
|   1.py
|   db.sqlite3
|   manage.py
+---products
|   |   admin.py
|   |    ...
|   +---migrations
|   +---templates
|   |       index.html
+---pyshop
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
+---static
|   |   press-single.html
|   |   single.html
|   |
|   +---admin
|   |   +---css
|   |   +---fonts
|   |   +---img
|   |   \---js
|   +---css
|   |   |   aos.css
|   |   |   bootstrap-datepicker.css
|   |   |   ...
|   |   |   style.css
|   |   |
|   |   \---bootstrap
|   |           bootstrap-grid.css
|   |           bootstrap-reboot.css
|   |           bootstrap.css
|   |
|   +---fonts
|   |   +---flaticon
|   |   \---icomoon
|   +---images
|   |       ac-nc-67336.svg
|   |       ...
|   |       trimble-2.svg
|   +---js
|   |       aos.js
|   |       ...
|   |       typed.js
|   |
|   \---scss
|       |   style.scss
|       |   _site-base.scss
|       |   _site-blocks.scss
|       |   _site-navbar.scss
|       |
|       \---bootstrap
+---templates
|       base.html
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Products</title>
</head>

<body>
{% block content %}

<div class="pb-5" style="position: relative; z-index: 8;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -50px;">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                <img src="../../templates/images/img_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                <h3 class="text-primary h4 mb-2">Business Analytics</h3>
                <p>Accusantium dignissimos voluptas rem consequatur ratione illo sit quasi.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                <img src="{% static 'images/img_2.jpg ' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                <h3 class="text-primary h4 mb-2">Investment Solutions</h3>
                <p>Praesentium magnam pariatur quae necessitatibus eligendi voluptate ducimus.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                <img src="{% static 'images/img_3.jpg ' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                <h3 class="text-primary h4 mb-2">Individual Approach</h3>
                <p>Accusantium dignissimos voluptas rem consequatur ratione illo sit quasi.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

> `base.html`

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Inves &mdash; Colorlib Website Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css ' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css ' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css ' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.css ' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css ' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css ' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-datepicker.css ' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css ' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aos.css ' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css ' %}">

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">
{% block content %}


{% endblock %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.sticky.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js ' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/aos.js ' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'js/main.js ' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pyshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {

        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pyshop.wsgi.application'


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': products})


# request object, html template, dictionary to import from db

def index2(request2):
    return HttpResponse('new page')
```

> `view page source`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

        <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Inves &mdash; Colorlib Website Template</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fonts/icomoon/style.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/magnific-popup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/aos.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">


    <div class="pb-5" style="position: relative; z-index: 8;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: -50px;">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                    <img src="../../templates/images/img_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                    <h3 class="text-primary h4 mb-2">Business Analytics</h3>
                    <p>Accusantium dignissimos voluptas rem consequatur ratione illo sit quasi.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                    <img src="/static/images/img_2.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                    <h3 class="text-primary h4 mb-2">Investment Solutions</h3>
                    <p>Praesentium magnam pariatur quae necessitatibus eligendi voluptate ducimus.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                    <img src="/static/images/img_3.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                    <h3 class="text-primary h4 mb-2">Individual Approach</h3>
                    <p>Accusantium dignissimos voluptas rem consequatur ratione illo sit quasi.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/aos.js"></script>

    <script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

[image]

> `actual webpage`

[image: actual webpage]

Edit :adding this to `settings.py` worked

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
```

]

Comment: What is rendering index.html?

Comment: `views.py` . added the src text.

Comment: Can you show more information about the error? Where is it happening? That does not seem to be a Django error and isn't about not finding the path.

Comment: my webpage isn't loading the images. and in every lines similar to `src="% static 'images/img_3.jpg ' %}` it is giving a warning `cannot resolve directory %static...`

Comment: But *what* is giving that warning? Show a screenshot if necessary.

Comment: As Ivan points out, you are clearly missing the opening bracket on two of those lines.

Comment: i corrected the opening curly brace, still the same error, wait uploading the ss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195631/discussion-between-afsara-ben-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: Am I correct that all of the Django template tags persist unchanged (not processed/rendered) in rendered page HTML (see "View source" in browser)?

Comment: I did not understand your question .In `view page source` when i click on the `static/css..` link it gives a `page not found error`

Comment: You have provided tons of irrelevant information. Are you asking about Pycharm warning or 404 status? These things are not really related.

Comment: But this error is from viewing the template file in your IDE. It's not at all relevant. What is important is what happens when you go to the URL in your browser, after the template is rendered.

Comment: i just want to know why it isn't loading the images :(

Comment: Please add to your question real image URL from rendered page and remove Pycharm screenshot - it does not help with anything.

Comment: Please replace **URL screenshot** with URL text value. And see updated answer.

Comment: URL text value added

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.py` add:

```
# Where default server looks for static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ROOT_DIR("static"),
]
```

Also you can try: `./manage.py collectstatic`

Edit:

The `ROOT_DIR` comes from here:

```
import environ

ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 3  # (/a/b/myfile.py - 3 = /)
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR('server/apps')
```

Comment: I added `STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR("static"),
]` and got the error 
`    BASE_DIR("static"),
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

`

Comment: also i ran `python manage.py runserver` previously which was succesful. the console msg was `119 static files copied to 'E:\py-projects\hello-world\static'.
`

Comment: it says `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'Path'
`

Comment: this  worked. `STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

]
`

Comment: This is the wrong way. You should set STATIC_ROOT instead and remove **destination** folder for `collectstatic` from `STATICFILES_DIRS` which is a list of (additional) **source** folders for `collectstatic`. Your current config will not work on prod.

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="% static 'images/img_2.jpg ' %}"`

1. opening curly bracket is missing here
2. and an unnecessary whitespace is present after the file name (before closing single quote) which results in surplus `%20` in the generated static file URL
3. You did not configure `STATIC_ROOT`

Note, you should remove **destination** folder (`os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`) for collectstatic from `STATICFILES_DIRS` which is a list of (additional) **source** folders for collectstatic. Your current config will not work on prod.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios one for static files other for media files.
for static files like your css,js,sass and other stuff you are required to create static directory and for images and videos you are required to create media directory.
Here in local development, you are required to create two folders one where static files will be fetched and one from where static files will be fetched.
when in production external services like AWS are used to fetch static or media files safely.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

works as collect the static files from another server which is configured in static URL.
hope you got the gist.
for setting up your static files [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YH-ipgxlJzs). which beautifully explains how to do it in an easy way.
also,
 `` STATICFILES_DIRS = [ BASE_DIR("static"), ] and got the error ` BASE_DIR("static"), TypeError: 'str' object is not callable `` 
Here BASE_DIR is an object holding the directory which is of string type. When you do this BASE_DIR("static") it is trying to call it as a function with a parameter.
that's why object not callable error. for all of your static files related queries in django watch the video.

Answer (score 0):

Place this line at the end of `settings.py`.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_ROOT,
]
```

After this you can access files in this directory in Django.
Hope it helped!

Comment: added it, it gave the error `ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

`

Comment: There's a reason those are separate settings. STATIC_ROOT is not the same as STATICFILES_DIRS and should not be inside it. Anyway, this clearly isn't the source of that error.

Comment: Try adding this snippet in your .html files, below doctype  
{% load staticfiles %}